# Why are questions closed as duplicates even if the target answers doesn't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I've came across this question: [How to configure log4j to only keep log files for the last seven days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683364/how-to-configure-log4j-to-only-keep-log-files-for-the-last-seven-days). The author asks about **DailyRollingFileAppender** (because that appender appends dates to date names).

It is closed as duplicate of [How can I get log4j to delete old rotating log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050256/how-can-i-get-log4j-to-delete-old-rotating-log-files), which is about **RollingFileAppender**. Quite important difference, because the second has the functionality, for which the OP asks, but it can't do daily rolling, which is what OP wants to use.

The question is, how could come to such mistake? Are the people that are closing questions, closing them without understanding the questions first? Is it a single mistake, or a system problem?

Comment: Mistakes happen. If they do, clarify the question and/or vote to reopen.

Comment: The system is human beings, so yes. It is a system problem. It is also a simple mistake.

Comment: The question may be a duplicate, but this does not guarantee an answer

Comment: @Skippy but it is **not** a duplicate, even if it could be after rewriting.

Comment: @WebDevie I am saying IF a question IS a duplicate, it doesn't guarantee there is an answer on the original. Not arguing, just adding

Answer (score 3):

You answered it quite well yourself - the second question offers functionality in the direction desired by the first question asker, and several answers on the first question also mention just RollingFileAppender. As well, if you take a certain perspective, both questions are asking the same thing - how to use log4j to delete files after a certain point. A user who is familiar enough with the technology to understand the basics, but not familiar enough to recognize that RollingFileAppender can't operate on a day-divided basis instead of a filesize basis, can easily see these as being the same question. The daily portion is certainly a requirement, but it's not immediately apparent that it is a breakpoint that nullifies the usability of the older question.

It's a system run by humans, where people can only vote based on their own knowledges. It's acceptable for users to make mistakes in voting questions to close, in the same way that it's acceptable to see users who are mistaken about trying to reopen a deservedly closed question. As long as people learn from the mistakes, the correct resolution occurs and we end up better on all fronts for this.